# Problems with express 4.x router and angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

i'm testing express 4.x with angular.js and i got some problems , someone got an error like this?

Console Chrome:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/javascript/main.js". localhost/:5
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.js:1
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/modulerr?p0=appTmo&p1=Error%3A…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.17%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A203)
```

My app is very simple:

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router  = express.Router();
var morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(router);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

router.get('*',function  (req,res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});


app.listen(8080);
```

index.html:

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
```

Comment: Clicking on the link in the error gives you the reason for the error 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=appTmo&p1=Error:%E2%80%A6gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.17%2Fangular.min.js:18:203)

Comment: Attach ```main.js``` and use non-minified version of Angular. Quite likely you are missing ```ng-app``` on your ```body``` tag.

Comment: ng-app is inside html tag

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `app.use(router);` below the `app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));`.  So your server.js should instead like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router  = express.Router();
var morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

app.use(router);
router.get('*',function  (req,res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});


app.listen(8080);
```

When you call `app.use(router)` prior to the static call, the router gets called first on requests.  The `*` matches all, so it'll process all incoming requests.  The problem you're seeing is that the `index.html` is being returned for the request for `main.js`.